# Difference between two random variables

Tags: convolution

Consider the case of two jointly continuous random variables. Assume that $G$ (generation process) and $L$ (load process) are jointly continuous random variables, with joint PDF given by $f_{G, L}(g, l)$, let $X = G + L$, then,

\begin{eqnarray} \label{eq:convolution}
\begin{split}
    F_X(x) &= \Pr(X \le x) \\
    &= \Pr(G + L \le x) \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{x-g} f_{G,L}(g, l)dl \right)dg\\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{x} f_{G,L}(g, t-g)dt \right)dg\\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{x} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{G,L}(g, t-g)dg \right)dt\\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{x} \left(f_x(t)\right)dt\\
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore, the PDF of $X$ is given by: 
$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{G,L}(g, x-g)dg$$

Since $G$ and $L$ can be assumed to be independently continuous random variables, then,

$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_G(g)f_L(x - g)dg = f_G * f_L$$

which is the convolution of the two marginal PDFs. 
Now if I require $Z = G - L$, I can rewrite this as $Z = G + (-L)$ to get:

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_G(g)f_{-L}(z - g)dg$$

Hence,

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_G(g)f_{L}(g - z)dg$$

If want to write this as a convolution like $f_G * f_L$, what will it be for $Z = G - L$. Will it remain as $f_G * f_L$?

Comment: why not simply $f_G * f_{-L}$?

Comment: I was thinking it could be that too, but I wasn't sure.  So I will just have to multiple the values in L by -1 and do the convolution as usual?